# Communication between k8s dashboard and metrics server

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, kubernetes-dashboard

How do k8s dashbaord and metrics server communicate? Just like in Prometheus scrapes metrics exposed via REST. How to check what exactly metrics server exposes?

Answer (score 0):

Metrics server is using [k8s metrics API](https://github.com/kubernetes/community/blob/master/contributors/design-proposals/instrumentation/resource-metrics-api.md) to export mertics to k8s.

Also check: [k8s monitoring architecture](https://github.com/kubernetes/community/blob/master/contributors/design-proposals/instrumentation/monitoring_architecture.md). This document proposes a high-level monitoring architecture for Kubernetes.

---

> How to check what exactly metrics server exposes

Use api endpoint:

```
kubectl get --raw "/apis/metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1/pods" | jq
kubectl get --raw "/apis/metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1/nodes" | jq
```

If you don't have any custom metrics exposed you will see that the only exposed metrics are CPU and Memory (for every pod/node).